# Math contest problem about 2 trains leaving the same station at different times

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I have a math problem from a math contest I will be taking soon that I simply cannot understand how they got their answer.

If Train A leaves at noon from San Francisco and heads for Chicago going 40 mph. 
Two hours later Train B leaves the same station, also for Chicago, traveling 60mph. 
How long until Train B overtakes Train A?

I got 6 P.M. but the answer key says 4 P.M.?

Comment: At $4$:$00$, train $A$ will have gone $4\times 40=160$ miles and train $B$ will have gone $2\times 60=120$ miles so that seems incorrect.

Comment: I thought about it some more and I believe it might have something to do with the time difference between the 2 cities? I believe Chicago is 2 hours ahead of San Francisco so it makes the answer 4 P.M. instead of 6 P.M. however, I'm not sure. If that is the case, then it has a bad answer because in the time the 2 trains travelled, they would not have crossed the timezone.

Comment: Well, I considered that...but A. it goes the wrong way (it's two hours later in Chicago).  and B.  at the meeting time they've gone $240$ miles, which is still in the same time zone ($240$ miles gets you just past Reno).

Comment: My guess:  they correctly worked out that they meet $4$ hours after train $B$ leaves the station, but then they incorrectly added that $4$ to the noon hour.

Comment: Also, the time zone difference shouldn't matter. It asks how much time until they meet. If a stopwatch was started in one traincar, the time zone difference wouldn't change the elapsed time.

Comment: You say that this is from a contest.  Can you please specify *which* contest this is from?

Comment: Hi, It's not a very known math competition as it is a local one, but it is called the Avinash Raina math competition.

Comment: The question, as you state it, asks _how long_ until Train B overtakes Train A. But you claim that the answer key says 4 P.M. That is not an answer to _how long_, it is an answer to _what time_. So I suspect that you have confused the two. Train B does indeed overtake Train A after four hours (which in some languages is the same as four o'clock!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time when the two trains will meet is going to be the solution to the following equation (the intersection of two straight lines) where $t\ge0$ and $t=0$ corresponds to $12:00$ PM (noon):

$$
40t=60(t-2)\implies\\
40t=60t-120\implies\\
t=6\ P.M.
$$

But the second train (B) departed at $2$ P.M. Therefore, it's $6-2=4$ hours before the second train (B) catches up with the first one (A). I don't know why it says P.M. in the answer key, but the answer to the question "how long until train B overtakes train A" should be the number of hours because it's the difference between two points in time designated as $6$ P.M. and $2$ P.M and that should be measured just in hours.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of 6pm as the time of passing is correct. In the two hours where only Train A is traveling, it goes a total of 80 miles (40mph x 2 hours). The relative velocity between the trains is 20mph (60mph - 40mph). So, it takes 4 hours for train B to close the 80 miles between the two trains (80 miles / 20mph). Since Train B left at 2pm, it will pass Train A at 6pm.

Train B takes 4 hours to pass Train A, and this occurs at 6pm. The question, as posted, asks **how long it takes for Train B to pass Train A**, so the answer is 4 hours, not 4pm or 6pm.

Answer (score 1):

Train B starts with a lag of $2\cdot40$ km.

It can make up $60-40$ km deficit in an hour

So, it will require $80/20$ hours to meet train $A$

Answer (score 0):

Train A leaves at time $t_{A0} = 0$ traveling at $40$ mph. Train B leaves at time $t_{B0} = t_{A0} + 2 = 2$ traveling at $60$ mph. Since velocity is distance divided by time (look at the units), we can write

$$v=\dfrac{d}{t}$$

Rearranging this yields the distance as a function of time:

$$d(t)=vt$$

Therefore, train A will have a distance of

$$d_A(t)=v_At = 40t$$

Train B will have a distance of

$$d_B(t)=v_Bt=60t$$

For the first two hours, train A travels alone, meaning it covers a distance of

$$d_A(2) = (40mph)\cdot(2hrs)=80miles$$

Now, making the start of train B our starting point, train A has an initial distance of $80$ miles, so it's distance becomes

$$d_A(t) = 80 +40t$$

Now we need to find the time that they meet, meaning we need to see when their distances are equal

$$\begin{align}d_A(t) &= d_B(t)
\\
80+40t&=60t
\\
80&=20t
\\
t&=4hours
\end{align}$$

We see that their time is $4$ hours from the start of train B, or $6$ hours from the start of train A. This implies that they meet at $6:00$ P.M.

Answer (score 0):

By the time train $B$ overtakes train $A$ each will make distance $S$.
Thus, "time travelled by train $B$" = S/60 = "time travelled by train $A - 2$ hours". In other words, $S/60 = S/40 -2$, so $S=240$ (miles). As train $B$ travels at $60$ mph it needs $4$ hours to overtake train $A$.